# Best way to convert RGB byte[][] image to byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing

Have frame data in the form of a byte[][] object, where each row corresponds to a (R,G,B) channel and is of length (frame width*frame height). I wish to convert it to a byte[] format in a similar vein as follows:

```
byte[][] original_frame;
byte[] converted_frame = convert(original_frame);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(frame);
BufferedImage bImage2 = ImageIO.read(bis);
```

From what I can tell, ImageIO assumes a jpeg format. Do I need to convert every frame to a JPEG image, or is there a more natural way to do this?

Comment: ImageIO is meant to load in files, if you need a BufferedImage from a byte array, you can create a WritableRaster and then convert that to a BufferedImage

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are asking how to convert from a 2D array to 1D array. How to do this if all rows are length 3 is as follows:

```
ArrayList<byte> x = new ArrayList<byte>();
for(int i=0; i<original_frame.length; i++){
   x.add(original_frame[i][0]);
   x.add(original_frame[i][1]);
   x.add(original_frame[i][2]);
}
byte[] converted_frame= new byte[x.size()];
for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++){
   converted_frame[i]=x.get(i);
}
```

I hope this helps